# How do I restrict page access in IIS based on access count?

Tags: php, http, iis, iis-7, iis-6

We have an internal user who has developed a few scripts to poll some of our internal tools at short intervals, such as every three seconds.

The user has spread the scripts (JS-based) to other employees.  As such, our server, which is IIS-based, receives numerous hits to certain tools every few seconds.

I believe that we could use PHP to stop this, but the fix would be ugly.
For example, Question 6202116 has an answer similar to what we would need for a PHP-based fix.

However, we believe that IIS 6.0 should be able to restrict access based on access counts (per IP).  For example, if a user tries to access a page more than 3 times within a two minute interval, access should be denied.

Anyone?

Comment: What about using the user agent to do the filtering?

Comment: Or what about returning a 301 status code and a new url, provided that the rogue scripts aren't smart enough to follow the new url?

Comment: We could use the user agent, but we just moved to IIS and don't know where to find the area where we can implement restrictions, regardless of using the user's reported agent.  Through searching for "user agent module" and "restrictions," I happened upon our answer:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/548/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions/